# iOS 8 JavaScript to UIWebView communication bug

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, uiwebview, uikit

New in iOS 8 is a bug that blocks the UI when more than a couple of JavaScript to native code communications take place.

Native to Javascript communication is via `UIWebView`'s `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`, and JavaScript to native is done via a custom URL Scheme.

If I do a three or more **webview -> native** communications, the first two happen immediately, however the subsequent ones take 10 seconds per communication to occur.

Anyone experiencing this?

**EDIT: 2014/09/23**

Specifically, the problem occurs if you do two javascript to native calls consecutively,

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"calliOS('aurlscheme://awebview?say=two'); calliOS('aurlscheme://awebview?say=cat');"];
```

where calliOS() is a JavaScript function that uses to [the iframe hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2935005/1305067) to call the native code through the URL scheme.

If you replace the iframe hack with a straight call to 'window.location',

`[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location='aurlscheme://awebview?say=two';window.location='aurlscheme://awebview?say=cat';"];`

You lose *all but the last* URL scheme request.

So in conclusion, **when making rapid consecutive javascript to native calls**, either you use the iframe hack and the UI freezes for a few seconds, or you use the `window.location` way and lose all but the last request.

Comment: I'm also interested in this. Can you get custom URL schemes to work at all? So far, I don't get notified of them in webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType on iOS 8.

Comment: Yes, it works for me, although I use `application:application handleOpenURL:url` to catch the request, parse the GET query string and the pass the dictionary of parameters to the corresponding view controller.

Comment: @AlexanderCollins, see my answer below, it works for me in iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me.

Every time JavaScript sends a request to the native code, the delegate method,

```
- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

must receive the request **before** the JavaScript sends a new request, otherwise we encounter all sorts of bugs. So, we implement a cache in the JavaScript to hold the pending requests, and only fire a new one once the previous request has been received.

*So, the solution is:*

***JavaScript***

```
// We need an array (cache) to hold the pending request URLs.
var iOSRequestCache = [];

/**
 Add a new iOS request to the cache.
 @params (Dictionary) - The query parameters to send to the native code.
 */
function newiOSRequest(parameters) {
    // Make the full request string.
    var str = [];
    for (var p in parameters)
        if (parameters.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(parameters[p]));
        }
    var queryString = str.join("&");

    var request = 'myurlscheme://webview?' + queryString;

    // Add the new request to the cache.
    iOSRequestCache.push(request);

    console.log("Added new request: " + request);

    // If this new request is the only one in the cache, fire it off to the native side. Else, do nothing.
    if (iOSRequestCache.length == 1) {
        console.log("Fired request: " + request);
        window.location = iOSRequestCache[0];
    }
}

/**
 Called by the native side to notify that a request was processed and to procced with the next pending request, if any.
 */
function resolveiOSRequest(request) {
    console.log("Resolving request: " + request);
    // Search for the processed request in the cache and delete it.
    var requestIndex = iOSRequestCache.indexOf(request);
    if (requestIndex != -1) {
        iOSRequestCache.splice(requestIndex, 1);   // Remove the request from the array.
    }
    console.log("Deleting resolving request: " + request);

    if (iOSRequestCache.length >= 1) {
        console.log("Firing next request: " + request);
        window.location = iOSRequestCache[0];
    }

    console.log("Resolved request: " + request);
}
```

**Objective-C (native code)**

```
/*
 Called whenever a URL is requested inside the web view.
 */
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType
{
    // The URL Scheme we use for web view <-> native communication (we grab it from the .plist file of the project target.)
    NSString *URLScheme = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleURLTypes"][0][@"CFBundleURLSchemes"][0];

    // If we get a request from this URL scheme, we grab the parameters and take the appropriate action.
    if ([inRequest.URL.scheme isEqualToString:URLScheme]) {
        // Get the query parameters.
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        NSArray *pairs = [inRequest.URL.query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
        for (NSString *pair in pairs)
        {
            NSArray *elements = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            NSString *key = elements[0];
            NSString *value = elements[1];
            key = [key stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            value = [value stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [params setObject:value forKey:key];
        }

        // Here we notify the JavaScript that we received this communication so that the next one can be sent.
        NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"resolveiOSRequest('%@')", inRequest.URL.absoluteString];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];

        // Call the method that handles our JavaScript to native requests.
        // HERE WE TAKE WHATEVER ACTION WE WANT WITH THE DICTIONARY THAT
        // THE JAVASCRIPT SENT US.
        [self handleWebViewMessage:params];
    }

    return YES;

}
```

**Usage:**

```
newiOSRequest({
    animal               : "cat",
    favfood              : "gocat",
});
```